# Assigning font-family via 'pre' tag

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I want to make sure a problem with a certain popular html-to-pdf tool isn't a misunderstanding of mine before I file a bug report.

The issue has to do with assigning fonts. The content is first converted from markdown, which adds inline `<code>` tags and block level `<pre><code>` tags.

The CSS includes:

```
pre { font-family: 'Foobar Sans Mono'; }
```

However, when this is used, the font is ignored in the converted pdf, whereas using this:

```
code { font-family: 'Foobar Sans Mono'; }
```

It isn't.  Viewing the html in a web browser, both are fine.  I realize considering the context assigning the font via `code` is probably preferable, but doing it via `pre` should still not be ineffectual.

Font is inherited, and [a `code` tag](http://file:///doc/HTML/W3C/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element), categorized as [a "phrasing" element](http://file:///doc/HTML/W3C/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1), should count as the child of the `pre` tag it is wrapped in, and thus inherit the `font-family` attribute.

Is that correct, or is there some point-of-order whereby the html-to-pdf tool is just being more strictly orthodox than the web browser?

Comment: Yes, `font` is inherited, but `code` has its own font-family in the default browser stylesheet, otherwise it couldn't be monospaced at all! What you want is `pre, pre *` for a selector.

Comment: @MrLister Using `pre, pre*` works -- if you can fluff that out into an answer I'll accept. The "default browser stylesheet" is perplexing -- in fact in the flawed pdf version, the code segments *weren't* monospace by default, but whatever that font was, it wasn't determined by  `body { font-family: ` or any other parent element.